# What is an example of an embedding which is not proper?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

An embedded submanifold is an immersed submanifold for which the inclusion map is a topological embedding. A properly embedded submaniold is one which is embedded and the inclusion map is proper. There are many classical examples of one-to-one immersions which are not emeddings e.g. a line of irrational slope on the 2-torus. The assiciated inclusion map in this case is obviously not proper, but I am having trouble thinking of an embedded submanifold which is not properly embedded. There are examples when the ambient manifold is not Hausdorff, for instance, but can someone think of an example when both manifolds are well behaved?

Comment: An embedded sub-manifold S is properly embedded if and only if it is a closed subset of M. So any non-closed embeddings are examples. For example, perhaps the most easy one: $(0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not properly embedded: the inverse image of the inclusion map of [0, 1] is (0, 1), which is not compact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of the embedding $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb S^n$, which image is $\mathbb S^n\setminus \{N\}$. Then, for any compact neighborhood $C$ of $N$ in $\mathbb S^n$, the inverse image of $C$ is not a compact space.

Comment: What is $N$ here?

Comment: @tparker I think it is the $\infty$ in the one-point compactification.

Comment: @tparker I think it is the north pole: $(0, 0, ..., 1)$.